# Case classes (as enums) and Json.reads

Tags: scala, playframework, play-framework-2.7

I have Carriers, they all have a name and a price
I wanted pattern matching on it, so I wrote them as case classes :

```
sealed abstract class Carrier( val name: String = "", val price: Double = 0, val img: Option[String] = None)

case object FREE extends Carrier("Frais de ports offerts via La Poste ou GLS", 0)

case class GLS(override val price: Double) extends Carrier("GLS", price)

case class LA_POSTE(override val price: Double) extends Carrier("Lettre ou colis (via La Poste)", price, Some("laposte-logo.png"))
...
```

But now I need to "jsonify" them. Must I write a formatter for each carrier ? Or is there a way to write a unique formatter in the `Carrier` class ?

I tried that :

```
object Carrier {
  implicit val fmtCarrier: Format[Carrier] = Json.format[Carrier]
}
```

But it does not compile, it says :

```
No instance of Reads is available for models.order.FREE in the implicit scope
```

Comment: There is no auto-materialization of `Reads` instances for the subtypes. You have to make them available in the implicit scope before that.